# Can tritiated water be separated from regular water with a centrifuge?

Tags: waste-water-treatment

Tritiated water should weigh more than regular water. Can they be centrifugally separated?

Comment: http://www.google.com/patents/US20050279129

Comment: Tritium separation?  Are you some kind of terrist out to blow up the grate country of Amirikka?  :-)